# How to get header information using http in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, excel

Here I have hard coded **fileName** but I want to get the filename from my spring service where I have already set the file name in header of http response. How to get the file name at js end.

```
$http.post('/myrest/rest/getVendorExcelDownload',$scope.exelReportInputDTO,{responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log("inside success");
        var fileName = "Vendor_Excel_Reports.xls";
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = objectUrl;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();

    }).error(function(data){
        console.log("inside error");
    });
```

Comment: Are you expecting the file name from Spring service? If yes, what is the response you are getting from the Spring controller?

Comment: yes I am using spring services and in response i am getting this.
byteLength:13824
__proto__
:
ArrayBuffer
byteLength
:
(...)
constructor
:
function ArrayBuffer()
slice
:
function slice()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
:
"ArrayBuffer"
get byteLength
:
function byteLength()
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Can you post your response and the Spring controller code for this service? I am not able to follow on your response that you have posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to get filename from header like this ..

```js
var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: '', //your API
  headers: {
    id: id // get your filename from header
  }
}
$http(req)
  .then(function mySucces(response) {
      //your success code!
    },
    function myError(response) {
      //your error code!
    });
```